# Command to switch to next/previous application

Tags: command-line, application-switcher

I'm interested in a command to switch to the next/previous application window in Ubuntu 16.04. I know I can do that through <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab ↹</kbd>, but I want to know which command is run on the background when the combination is pressed.

One interesting behavior that would be useful (but not necessary) is that this command would not only raise the next application in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab ↹</kbd> list, but also raise each window of the same application each time it is invoked, if one application happens to have more than one window open.

Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shortcuts control the window manager, to do the same using terminal commands there's `wmctrl`. Here are some usage examples:

- list  the  windows  being  managed by the window manager

  ```
  wmctrl -l
  ```
- switch to the desktop containing Firefox, raise the window and give it focus

  ```
  wmctrl -a firefox
  ```
- move Firefox to the current desktop, raise the window and give it focus

  ```
  wmctrl -R firefox
  ```
- Toggle “fullscreen” and “stay above“ mode for currently active window

  ```
  wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,fullscreen,above
  ```
- Select a window by clicking on it, maximize it horizontally and make it invisible for the taskbar

  ```
  wmctrl -r :SELECT: -b add,maximized_horz,skip_taskbar
  ```

Read [`man wmctrl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=wmctrl) and [wmctrl‘s homepage](https://sites.google.com/site/tstyblo//wmctrl/) for more. The window properties available for the `-b` option may partially be specific to the window manager in use, use `wmctrl -m` to get its name and search from there – or just try it out.

Answer (score -1):

In Ubuntu 17.04 these keyboard commands are active...

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> = switch open applications

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> = switch open windows (displayed first by <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>)

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> = switch open windows directly

To check for other useful keyboard commands, open the keyboard settings and check the shortcut settings.